# Phonegap Build application icon missing

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I've uploaded my application to PhoneGap Build service, but I cannot get my application icon to show in PhoneGap Build.  My app icons are showing correctly in the iOS and Android apps that are generated.  My app icon does not show up in PhoneGap itself.  It defaults to Phonegap app icon.

[image]

I assume there's a setting in config.xml that is used for the app icon in PhoneGap build.  I have the following lines in config.xml:

```
<!--DEFAULT ICON-->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

icon.png is part of the upload to phongapBuild.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: That is the correct code for the icon in PGB. Is it in the right folder. Remember - you have no "img/" folder.

Comment: i have icon.png in same folder as config.xml (root folder)

Comment: Is it the right size?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Please see if your config.xml file is in the same folder as index.html and in that same folder you make a separate folder named icon and place icon.png in that folder. You are also making the mistake of not giving icon a default tag:

```
<icon src="img/icon.png" gap:role="default" />
```

give it a try!

Comment: that seems like it would work, but it didnt for me.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom, it is not clear to me what the correct parameters are to accomplish this, but I got the ICON to show up. You can see the ICON in [my public page for my SplashPage demo](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1362035/share). The source code is on github under https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test.

Let me know if you figure it out. I will document it. --Jesse

Answer (score 0):

The way to get it to work for iOS 7.0+ w/ Phonegap CLI 6.5.0 is to create the right icon sizes for iOS as detailed here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/

I faced a similar problem until I updated my icon sizes from my old Phonegap 5.2.x sizes.